Pip breaks with AttributeError
I am trying to install pillow, however this is what happened:
> pip3 install pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 78, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 64, in <module>
    WRAPPERS = {
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 64, in <dictcomp>
    WRAPPERS = {
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 196, in iterator
    for name in resource.resources:
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\util.py", line 465, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 115, in resources
    return self.finder.get_resources(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 180, in get_resources
    return set([f for f in os.listdir(resource.src_path) if allowed(f)])
AttributeError: 'ResourceContainer' object has no attribute 'src_path'

All operations with pip and pip3, including upgrade pip, result in the exact error above.
I am working in a virtual env, the global pip works just fine but the venv pip fails.
The last thing i did with pip was installing customtkinter
More details:
> py -m pip list
Package       Version
------------- ---------
customtkinter 5.2.2
darkdetect    0.8.0
easygui       0.98.3
mido          1.3.2
numpy         2.0.1
opencv-python 4.10.0.84
packaging     23.2
pip           24.2
setuptools    60.2.0
wheel         0.37.1

Python version:
> py --version
Python 3.9.6

Pip version:
py -m pip --version
pip 24.2 from D:\Users\USER\Project\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)


pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py, line 180. I checked multiple Pythons and site-packages at my host and none has resource.src_path at the line, all have resource.path. Where from have you got the code? You didn't edit it, did you?

@phd Nope I did not edit anything, that's one of the most horrifying things to do. I think it probably corrupted so I recreated another venv from scratch using Python 3.12 and it's now ok

I am still curious about why my original venv's pip breaks so ill leave this question open, thanks for your effort @phd

Does the same happen with py -3.9 -m pip install -U pillow ?  I would also recommend updating from 3.9 if possible. You could also setup a venv and install using that interpreter.

I just created an equivalent environment, matching all your versions, using Miniconda on my Windows machine, and I cannot reproduce the error. My bet is your env was corrupted in a way that won't be reproducible.
